# compliation error and execution error of store procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

This is my stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure EMP_DB.std_stdsp
( stid  in out varchar(10),
 name   in out varchar(100)
)
is 
begin
select *from students s
where S.STDID in(stid)
and S.STDNME in (name);
end EMP_DB.std_stdsp;
/
```

compilation error

Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

When i execute stored procedure,i got an error

```
EXEC EMP_DB.std_stdsp('1','Farhat');
```

Error

```
BEGIN EMP_DB.std_stdsp('1','Farhat'); END;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00905: object EMP_DB.STD_STDSP is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Any one help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do `show errors` immediately after the `create` statement; or query the `user_errors` view later. Either will show you the actual compilation errors, the latter for all objects that are currently invalid so you can filter on the object type and name if you have a lot to sift through.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you intend to get multiple records back from the select.  To handle the multiple records, you'll need a loop.  The following should compile (sorry, didn't test)

```
create or replace procedure EMP_DB.std_stdsp ( 
     stid  in out varchar(10),
     name   in out varchar(100)) is 
begin
  for rec in (select *
                from students s
                where S.STDID in(stid)
                  and S.STDNME in (name)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line ('student record');
    -- replace the dbms_output and this comment with some meaningful code
    -- any code inside the loop will execute once for each student record 
    -- returned from the select statement
  end loop;
end EMP_DB.std_stdsp;
/
```

The second error is just because your procedure didn't compile.

Is your intent to pass something like `'1,3,5'` in to the `stid` parameter to get records 1, 3 and 5.  If that's the case, it's not going to work as intended.  The in will take the entire `'1,3,5'` as a single value.  To match a record in the table, the `stdid` column would have to be `'1,2,3'` exactly.  You can switch it around to use `like` instead of `in` if you want to get multiple records.  You'll have to add some wildcards though.